# How to check if a char is in the alphabet in C#

Tags: c#, char, alphabet

I think the title says enough.

```
void onClickSubmit(char submit)
{
     if(submit.//check if it is alphabetical)
     {
           //some code
     }
}
```

how can i check if the char submit is in the alphabet?

Comment: What do you consider your alphabet? Is it just anything `[a-zA-Z]`? Or do you have a special alphabet?

Comment: Or any letter character [`Char.IsLetter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Did you bother Googling/researching this *at all* before asking? What have you actually tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check first character of a string if a letter, any letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560393/how-to-check-first-character-of-a-string-if-a-letter-any-letter)

Comment: Is Ы part of your alphabet? And ㅂ? Not so *obvious*, maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use regex if your alphabet are only A-Z or a-z

```
char a = 'A';
bool isAlphaBet = Regex.IsMatch(a.ToString(), "[a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if(isAlphaBet )
{
    //do this..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To support any UTF-8 Letter

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"[\p{L}]");
Console.Write(rgx.Match("Ö").Success);
```